# Networking issue with photon, Joined room success but other player not seen

Tags: unity, photon

I am trying to add networking to my game via Photon Realtime and have a unity scene set up with this script attached to one of my game objects :

```
public class Multiplayer : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
}

public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
    Debug.Log("OnConnectedToMaster() was called by PUN.");
    RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
    roomOptions.IsVisible = false;
    roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 4;
    PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom("ChunckyMonkey", roomOptions, TypedLobby.Default);
}


public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    base.OnJoinedRoom();
    Debug.Log("Room was Joined.");
}


public override void OnJoinRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
{
    base.OnJoinRoomFailed(returnCode, message);
}
}
```

I can see the corresponding logs in unity's output but when I run the game with two oculus headsets I do not see the other player. So it seems to be working according to photon but I don't see it. This is using quest 2 unity version 2019.4.31f1.  Could photon be configured incorrectly or sending each player to a new room ?

Comment: Since you are setting the room to private with isinvisible and you can't join a private room by random joining, you should include the relevant code on how you make sure the two people are actually in the same room.

Comment: Hehe very silly of me, I did change it to public and still no luck. Says connected but when  putting the headset on with another person I don't see them in the same scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was silly of me. In addition to needing the room `isVisible` to be set to `true`, you have to set `isOpen` to `true` for others to be able to join. Makes sense.